# Bundle Identifier (App ID Suffix)

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile

when creating the AppID for my provisioning profile, i am a bit confused about a point in the documentation, it has been said that you can use either:

`com.domainname.appname` or `com.domainname."`

In which case it is recommended each Bundle please.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Second one is Wildcard App ID. And it should looks like `com.domainname.*`. Instead of * you can use any valid name for your project. You can use this ID for all your projects and you don't have to create new ID and new provision profile for each application you want to build and test.

But if you would like to develop app which will use Push Notifications or InAppPurchase, then you have to use explicit App ID. In this case Apple should know about your app to successful delivery information.