# What are the rules for bundle ID uniqueness?

Tags: ios

I have seen various claims that [bundle IDs must be unique](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11347680/179715), but it's not clear exactly what that means. ([Apple's documentation on bundles](https://developer.apple.com/go/?id=bundle-structure) doesn't seem to directly mention uniqueness at all.) It's not obvious to me whether such claims are describing bundle IDs in general or are specifically about the main application bundle.

It seems completely sensible that the main *application* bundle ID would need to be registered and therefore be unique among all other macOS or iOS applications.

However, if an application includes other bundles (such as frameworks), must they also have unique IDs?  If so, unique to what?  The system?  The application?  I am guessing that such bundles need only be unique to the application; otherwise how would it work if two applications used the same framework?

Comment: Every bundle ID needs to be unique. It helps you connect to some online thing like Google Firebase. You should normally follow the standard of the **com.developer.app** to avoid duplications.

Comment: @George_E_2 So how do frameworks (with multiple versions) work?

Comment: As a matter of fact, I was literally reading about a very similar thing :) I was reading this website as I'm trying to implement a framework: http://iosbrain.com/blog/2018/01/13/building-swift-4-frameworks-and-including-them-in-your-apps-xcode-9/ Check the bottom part under **MAKING CHANGES TO THE CUSTOM FRAMEWORK**. Frameworks should have only one bundle ID